# Increment a column in sql until 45 then restart at 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, increment, mysql-5.7

this function dosen't work well:

```
$st = $dbh->query("SELECT * from player.player_gift");
    $test = $st->fetchAll();

    if(isset($_POST['pregatit'])) {

        foreach($test as $test2) {

            if(!is_null($test2['owner_id'])) {
                $st = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE player.player_gift SET pos = ? WHERE owner_id = ?');
                $st->execute([getRandomPositionFor($test2['owner_id']), $test2['owner_id']]);
            } else {
                // wh_log('id ul' . $test2['owner_id'] . 'a dat eroare');
            }
        }

        die();
    }

function getRandomPositionFor($ownerid) {
        static $lastposinserted = 0;
        static $lastownerid = -1;
        $lastownerid = $ownerid;

        if($lastownerid != $ownerid) 
            $lastposinserted = 0;

        if($lastposinserted > 60)
            $lastposinserted = 0;

        $lastposinserted++;

        return $lastposinserted;
    }
```

this one is make the column from db like this:

| owner_id | pos |
| --- | --- |
| 204,412 | 19 |
| 204,412 | 19 |
| 204,412 | 19 |
| 204405 | 24 |
| 204405 | 24 |
| 204405 | 24 |
| 204405 | 24 |
| 204390 | 48 |
| 204390 | 48 |
| 204390 | 48 |

I want them to be like this:

| owner_id | pos |
| --- | --- |
| 204,412 | 1 |
| 204,412 | 2 |
| 204,412 | 3 |
| 204405 | 1 |
| 204405 | 2 |
| 204405 | 3 |
| 204405 | 4 |
| 204390 | 1 |
| 204390 | 2 |
| 204390 | 3 |

and if is pos bigger than 60 then back to 1

Comment: Demo: https://3v4l.org/bb77a this code just produces "1" every time, it doesn't produce the results you're claiming. Why? Because you reset `$lastposinserted` and `$lastownerid` every time the function runs. So it never remembers any history. You'd need to declare those variables in a structure outside the function, and pass them in each time (or perhaps, make them properties of a class the function belongs to, and refer to them when the function runs, so they can hold the state in between calls).

Comment: @ADyson oh, ok this is strange, but look https://prnt.sc/PLhUkk7Hp7-z i have a same version with $GLOBALS variables and same thing, thank you for answer

Comment: `same version with $GLOBALS variables`...what does that mean? If your real code is different than what you showed above, please share that version instead.

Comment: @ADyson https://prnt.sc/i3EY4XPy7tRb i mean same thing but now i have 2 and 17

Comment: You said in a comment you're using MySQL 5.6.5. This is a [_beta_ release from 2012](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-5.html). Come on, it's time to upgrade.

Comment: It's not the same as the code you showed here. Please [edit] the question to contain the code you are actually talking about, not some different version. Details are important in programming.

Comment: @BillKarwin i dont think this is the problem, is a old game who work on this

Comment: @ADyson yeap, sorry for the mistake, now is same, look https://prnt.sc/AaU4kda-GwGq same thing i get

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. Unless I made some wrong assumption in my demo? Did you compare it in detail to your version?

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL 8.x you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`.

If the rows must has a fixed order, you need to add a column that sorts the rows:

```
UPDATE player.player_gift 
SET pos = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY owner_id ORDER BY RAND())
```

You are missing a primary key, so you need to add one if you want that all works properly:

```
CREATE TABLE player_gift
(
    `owner_id` varchar(7),  
    `pos` int
);
    
INSERT INTO player_gift (`owner_id`, `pos`)
VALUES
    ('204,412', 19),
    ('204,412', 19),
    ('204,412', 19),
    ('204405', 24),
    ('204405', 24),
    ('204405', 24),
    ('204405', 24),
    ('204390', 48),
    ('204390', 48),
    ('204390', 48)
;
```

> ```
> Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
ALTER TABLE player_gift Add column id1 BIGINT Auto_increment primary key;
UPDATE
  player_gift
 JOIN (SELECT id1,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY owner_id ORDER BY id1) rn FROM player_gift) t1
 ON player_gift.id1 = t1.id1 
  
SET player_gift.pos = rn;
ALTEr TABLe player_gift DROP column id1
```

> ```
> Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

> ```
> Rows matched: 10  Changed: 10  Warnings: 0
> ```

> ```
> Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM player_gift
```

| owner_id | pos |
| --- | --- |
| 204,412 | 1 |
| 204,412 | 2 |
| 204,412 | 3 |
| 204405 | 1 |
| 204405 | 2 |
| 204405 | 3 |
| 204405 | 4 |
| 204390 | 1 |
| 204390 | 2 |
| 204390 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M6Riykpv)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i'm using mysql 5.6.5

Comment: MySQL 5.x is reaching end of life in 10 months. Maybe it's a good idea to upgrade.

Comment: @TheImpaler i get same thing on mariadb 10.4.27 using xampp

Comment: @Filip.Filip. i updated my answer for mariadb 10.4